# Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Error shows up on my desktop?

Tags: windows-10, visual-c++, runtime-error

I usually leave my computer running throughout the day and just put it to sleep when I'm not on it. Whenever I open my computer I get this Error message verbatim:

> Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
>
> Runtime Error!
>
> Program: C:\WINDOWS\system32\atibtmon.exe
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.  Please contact the application's support team for more information.

I've done a few google searches on this problem, but most of the solutions were found because the program in question (the atibtmon.exe I think?) was conflicting with another program being used and/or the person was able to download something to help them get rid of the error message. The error message pops up for me on my desktop before I open any programs, so I'm not sure what it could be conflicting with. I also recently upgraded to Windows 10 if that is of any significance.

If someone could explain what this error means and a way for me to solve it/get rid of it without having to download or use an outside source, I would greatly appreciate that!

Comment: Check the event logs for a more detailed error message. [What information appears in event logs? (Event Viewer)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Related: [When AC Power is disconnected, atibtmon.exe throws a Runtime error](http://superuser.com/questions/510331/when-ac-power-is-disconnected-atibtmon-exe-throws-a-runtime-error), and [How do I disable Vari-Bright (atibtmon.exe) without Catalyst Control Center?](http://superuser.com/questions/639990/how-do-i-disable-vari-bright-atibtmon-exe-without-catalyst-control-center?lq=1).  So, to start: Try updated ATI drivers, and/or disabling Vari-Bright.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 i'll look into these as well as check out the error message and see if either helps